# Resolve object recursively with type safe property access in two steps

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to replace the string types in the following function with more specific types that ensure type safe property access:

```
import {get} from 'lodash';

const obj = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: {
    a: 'Hello',
    b: {c: 'World'}
  }
};

function factory(namespace?: string) {
  return function getter(key: string) {
    return get(obj, [namespace, key].filter((part) => part != null).join('.'));
  };
}

const getter = factory('bar');
getter('b.c'); // 'World'
```

The dot notation indicates a nested property access. It can be present both in the `namespace` as well as in the `key`.

So far I've found out that I can type `namespace` with this utility:

```
type NestedKeyOf<ObjectType extends object> =
  {
    [Key in keyof ObjectType & (string | number)]: ObjectType[Key] extends object
      ? `${Key}` | `${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<ObjectType[Key]>}`
      : `${Key}`
  }[keyof ObjectType & (string | number)];
```

Usage: `namespace?: NestedKeyOf<typeof obj>`.

I'm struggling however to come up with a dynamic type that is automatically assigned to `key`.

Two additional requirements would be:

1. A namespace should only ever resolve to an object (no leaf strings).
2. A getter should always resolve to a leaf string (no objects).

It can be assumed that only objects and strings are present in the object, nothing else.

```
// Test cases

// Should pass
factory()('foo')
factory('bar')('a')
factory('bar')('b.c')

// Invalid property access
// @ts-expect-error 
factory('baz')
// @ts-expect-error
factory('bar')('d')

// Only partial namespaces are allowed
// @ts-expect-error 
factory('foo')

// Getter calls need to resolve to a leaf string
// @ts-expect-error
factory('bar')('b')
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't believe this abomination actually works:

```
function factory<NestedKey extends NestedKeyOf<typeof obj>>(namespace?: NestedKey) {
  return function getter<
    TargetKey extends 
      (NestedKey extends undefined
        ? NestedKeyOf<typeof obj>
        : NestedKeyOf<Get<typeof obj, NestedKey>>)
  >(key: TargetKey): NestedKey extends undefined ? Get<typeof obj, TargetKey> : Get<typeof obj, `${NestedKey}.${TargetKey}`> {
    return get(obj, [namespace, key].filter((part) => part != null).join('.'));
  };
}
```

Allow me to explain. First of all, I had a lot of trouble with your implementation of NestedKeyOf :(

I had to rewrite it because it reported that type instantiation was too deep, so here is my version:

```
type NestedKeyOf<O> = O extends object ? {
    [K in keyof O]: `${K & string}` | `${K & string}.${NestedKeyOf<O[K]>}`;
}[keyof O] : never;
```

It does the same thing; just written differently. Next we need to be able to "deep get" a property (mimicking lodash's get function):

```
type Get<O, P extends string> =
  P extends `${infer Key}.${infer Rest}`
    ? Key extends keyof O ? Get<O[Key], Rest> : never
    : P extends keyof O ? O[P] : never;
```

The extra `extends keyof O` are there to prevent errors on invalid property access.

And finally the monstrosity I showed above.

We need to store what `namespace` is, so we use a generic. With this generic aptly named `NestedKey` we can now use it in the definition of `getter`.

`getter` also takes a nested key. However its type differs when `namespace` is not provided.

That is why `NestedKey extends undefined` is there. If it is not present, then `key` should be a nested key of the original object. Otherwise, it is a nested key of the value that `namespace` points to, using `Get`.

Finally in the return value, we do the same thing. If `NestedKey` is not present, then we deep get the target key, otherwise, we deep get the nested key and the target key.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwOYFMYF84DMoRHAcgBsIATAQwGcALAgbgFgAoZmATzBTgDkVKYUpANIo2AeSwAeMQD44AXjhi4KAB4CAdqUpwIAIwBWKAMbwA-ImZxrcANpC4wDXADWoiFiUBdAFxwABgAkCA4AZHD8UE5I6P5wAD4BwWERMFEaMQB0wbz8giLiUmL2XjKxjEzotm5sHt5wfhooAG4oUBWsHFwA4mjSADRwAAoq6ihaOpHRcvJWw6Oa2kkITlhtcAXo2Ssaa1BwAEp8GP5z1hYFC+NLNXXKFr0w0vaiXoNH-HKNLW1nDfNqRY6W6ee5KWxDLz-JqtdrMZjGCAafi6QwKSxMaxYCAQPwEbEQAj9OZ6chQPwIP7kPEACRQRBIRL+egpxjxAHVoERSAR0HM+ZU4FQ4IjkTAOkwsABXDSmYBI7DkUzQNiSXICYSiK4THjHfKiCSSdicOr6AwyGQACg05BAfDASpQZj86v1bAAlBjrFA0FKoM5pbKYPLnKgYAIoJI-gAVMlhy6A646P7WS2uzVsbVLGWkFBYJyCFM2CzpgqG40oU2GGRF6wuvUZw2PI1dKsGQal0QW91zK01PyxqDx0Tu+t5DNZnQ5vMF0hwB59CttwaD4dsL5wZtLzxmwZBBCdthbYKrtCbfxySmYmw+mB+0NoS27uw2u2UB3GFCDGpeTL5ogRpaloOrAnryHIIHwAAhIoGhSgy7qZAYEBOJaBCZAQ7ruhU1joBUAoIkiKJhhG6JYEqMAqpa2HMCRbRoXomTGJhdBwAA9GxhCclA3IEEAA)

The `as const` assertion is to verify that it is actually deep getting the correct value.

---

Update according to the new requirements. We'll need some new types to tell us which keys are objects and which are strings:

```
type GetObjectKeys<O, K extends string> = {
  [P in K]: Get<O, P> extends string ? never : P;
}[K];

type GetStringKeys<O, K extends string> = {
  [P in K]: Get<O, P> extends string ? P : never;
}[K];
```

They take an object type, and some potential keys. It checks each key's type. In the case of objects, if it is a string, it is `never`, otherwise `P`. We use `never` because below we will get a union of all the remaining keys with `[K]` and `T | never` simplifies to `T`.

Then because of `namespace` is optional it introduces some difficulties. An error on my part was believing that if `namespace` was not provided, `NestedKey` would be undefined (so the previous answer is actually incorrect). This is corrected later.

To address the optional `namespace`, we make the original `factory` function's parameter `namespace` *not* optional and rename it to `_factory` (internal/private). Then we create a new `factory` function that calls it like so:

```
function factory<NestedKey extends GetObjectKeys<typeof obj, NestedKeyOf<typeof obj>>>(namespace?: NestedKey) {
  return _factory<
    { __private: typeof obj },
    GetObjectKeys<typeof obj, NestedKeyOf<typeof obj>> extends NestedKey ? "__private" : `__private.${NestedKey}`
  //@ts-ignore Unfortunately I don't think there is a good way to prevent this error
  >({ __private: obj }, namespace ? `__private.${namespace}` : "__private");
}
```

It expects any object keys, but if the namespace was not provided it will create default to `__private`, because we wrap the target object in another object with a property `__private` to get around the fact that the namespace is optional. Think of this as a delegator.

Now for the modified `_factory` function:

```
function _factory<Obj extends unknown, NestedKey extends NestedKeyOf<Obj>>(obj: Obj, namespace: NestedKey) {
  return function getter<
    TargetKey extends GetStringKeys<Get<Obj, NestedKey>, NestedKeyOf<Get<Obj, NestedKey>>>
  >(key: TargetKey): Get<Obj, `${NestedKey}.${TargetKey}`> {
    return get(obj, [namespace, key].filter((part) => part != null).join('.'));
  };
}
```

This function is mostly the same as the original except now it only expects keys that result in strings. The part that handles the optional `namespace` is moved into the new `factory` function.

I could've chosen better names for `factory` and `_factory` to avoid confusion, but hopefully you've followed me through this well enough.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwOYFMYF84DMoRHAcgBsIATAQwGcALAgbgFgAoZmATzBTgDkVKYUpANIo2AeSwAeMQD44AXjhi4KAB4CAdqUpwIAIwBWKAMbwA-ImZxrcANpC4wDXADWoiFiUBdAFxwABgAkCA4AZHD8UE5I6P5wAD4BwWERMFEaMQB0wbz8giLiUmL2XjKxjEzotm5sHt5wfhooAG4oUBWsHFwA4mjSADRwAAoq6ihaOpHRcvJWw6Oa2kkITlhtcAXo2Ssaa1BwAEp8GP5z1hYFC+NLNXXKFr0w0vaiXoNH-HKNLW1nDfNqRY6W6ee5KWxDLz-JqtdrMTqcOCPMSGEwwAqUAYbK4TVLpJAzSxMawQxzOIS+JF9MSDIZyQHXSZpaJwCww9Z+IYVKoUjpMdiIx4AZWZGQxWIcDNxUwyhIQc1JTg2lMeWLpOKWMqQrPm31h3JKfOMEA0-F0hgUROsWAgED8BBtEAI-TmenIUD88uJNnI9oAEigiCRnX89J7jPaAOrQIikAjoOYJypwKhwY2mmB8rAAVw0pmAJrgAH0sORTNA2NILVKlrmXBoIAB3DSDXICYSiDU6Nv5UQSKsGGQyAAU+gMfhRBkGGnIID4YDLKD8PY7bAAlFa4FA0NmoM4c3mYAXnKgYAIoJI-gAVd2ny41nTC0VIcWqyet469tgyD95Vf9t9DF-dsCiHGQ5hHGo-BvKA71ENc-EAqdlhXTZthguC2FiOQvRsLcdz3OBT1HIC7BnOdKAXYwUEGGovEyLBgCIc9h2HBdYA3eQ5HY+AAEJFA0bMgzXTIDAgJxhwITICDXNcKmsdBuXhJgD3zQtS3LKBK1QzsHypGBJzRcUBRQOox2Ar9+xMszDDA4dyPnRczGXT9Vw3XD8JgXdnBLMsYArS9vWsBBiyLMAomacgBD8azPDHOB0BdIL9MM0xjK6GzkJ0wpJFi81B3pMZcWynUACIizCiKopQUr-n8CrwuASKBG2bLYjmAB6DqAAEYEoABaYAkAbbc4AAVV2aAvJnAQiDYOAAEk4FIE0CHgGBqCcFw4A2touGAHRyCI21SDgRtyHm-y4HCn4NHWzadDaXAoAg4cQoaqrovyhLp1nRzqJ1erKqa6rtgcyjF1if5yuB5qark5gk2YdMzVPc9LQ0-ytOHBGmDRtph1Kt0oEyPRMmMUq5LgLrCGjKBYwIZggA)

btw this is overengineered to ****; it always is when you start making types act like real code

Comment: Wow, this is incredible – thank you so much for your super helpful answer @kellys!

I've played around with your solution and the only call that I'd expect to work, but currently is a type error is this one: `factory()('foo')`. Somehow `namespace` seems to default to `bar`.

Apart from this, for my particular use case I found that it'd be great to handle two more requirements:
1. A namespace should only ever resolve to an object (no leaf strings).
2. A getter should always resolve to a leaf string (no objects).
I've added them to the question above.

Comment: I've added some test cases to my question above. If you happen to have any further thoughts, that would be incredible! Many thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will take a look when I can

Comment: @amann I believe I addressed your requirements in my edited answer

Comment: The provided solution worked really well for me so far, but I found that there is a problem with this line:

`GetObjectKeys<typeof obj, NestedKeyOf<typeof obj>> extends NestedKey ? "__private" : "__private.${NestedKey}"`

I found that when there's only a single namespace in the object, the expression wrongly evaluates to `__private` and not `__private.${NestedKey}`.

Issue for reference with a simplified TS playground link I'm trying to get working: https://github.com/amannn/next-intl/issues/112#issuecomment-1139399816

Comment: Sorry, I'm in school right now without a proper workplace. I will definitely take a look as soon as I can in 5 hours.

Comment: Oh no problem at all! If you don't mind lending a hand again that would be really kind of you! Thank you very much for your help so far @catgirlkelly!

Comment: Actually you could try to wrap the GetObjectKeys<...> and NestedKey with brackets (wrap into tuple of length 1). I think it's got something to do with naked types.

Comment: @amann Hey I figured it out and commented on the issue with my fix.