# Typescript - How to correctly type the return when accessing a nested object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have this interface and this function, which represents the object I want to access.

```
export interface IResources {
  logo: string
  favicon: string
  header: {
    menus: IRouterItem[]
  }
  footer: {
    menus: IRouterItem[]
  }
  links?: ILinkItem[]
}

getResource<K extends keyof IResources>(key: K): IResources[K] | null {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.temaAtivo.resources, key)
      ? (this.temaAtivo.resources[key] as IResources[K])
      : null 
}
```

And this function, which used worked perfectly:
[image]

But now I would like to access and
correctly return the value from nested properties like so `this.getResourcee('header.menus')`.
I would like to receive one or more properties and still correctly return the type, but I couldn't. This is the function I'm trying to achieve

```
getResource<K extends RecursiveKeyOf<IResources>>(key: K) {
    return key.split('.').reduce((acc, current) => {
      return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(acc, current)
        ? acc[current]
        : null
    }, this.temaAtivo.resources)
  }
```

Update:

RecursiveKeyof its working
[image]

What i want to achieve:

```
getResource<K extends RecursiveKeyOf<IResources>>(
    key: K
  ): IResources[K] | IResources[K][K] | null {
    return key.split('.').reduce((acc: IResources | IResources[k], current: keyof IResources | keyof IResources[k]) => {
      return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(acc, current)
        ? acc[current]
        : null
    }, this.temaAtivo.resources)
  }
```

Update 2.0 - [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65332597/typescript-is-there-a-recursive-keyof)

```
export type RecursiveKeyOf<TObj extends object> = {
  [TKey in keyof TObj & (string | number)]: RecursiveKeyOfHandleValue<
    TObj[TKey],
    `${TKey}`
  >
}[keyof TObj & (string | number)]

type RecursiveKeyOfInner<TObj extends object> = {
  [TKey in keyof TObj & (string | number)]: RecursiveKeyOfHandleValue<
    TObj[TKey],
    `['${TKey}']` | `.${TKey}`
  >
}[keyof TObj & (string | number)]

type RecursiveKeyOfHandleValue<
  TValue,
  Text extends string
> = TValue extends any[]
  ? Text
  : TValue extends object
  ? Text | `${Text}${RecursiveKeyOfInner<TValue>}`
  : Text
```

Comment: Creating typesafe nested dotted path notation is tricky, but possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057649/typescript-string-dot-notation-of-nested-object

Comment: Will you need this to work with arrays (ex `header.menus.0.somePropertyOnIRouterItem`)?

Comment: @AlexWayne That's only the first half, they also want the function to return the correct type for the deep key.

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/WKq2pN) is a **super overkill solution** that covers arrays *as well as tuples*.

Comment: The RecursiveKeyOf its working, so I was able to achieve 'header.menu' param. The problem is to properly type reduce and the main function return.  When i split the key into ['header', 'menu'] typescript treats each as string, and not keyof IResources. Also treats acc as IResources.  I've updated my question. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Would you mind sharing the definition of `RecursiveKeyOf`? You can try the `Get` type from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71529277/resolve-object-recursively-with-type-safe-property-access-in-two-steps/71529575#71529575) answer for the return type.

Comment: @catgirlkelly dont mind at all. I'm sorry, but I don't remember the source. I'm new to typescript and I didn't create it. I've updated my question